# How to iterate a linked hashset and compare each 2 elements in a text file in java?

Tags: java, linkedhashset

I have some elements in a linked hash set.Example
pencil,pen,eraser,scale
First I want to access (pencil,pen) and perform some operation. Then I want to access (pencil,eraser) then (pencil,scale) and so on.
I have written a code which can access 1st two items but in next iteration it accesses eraser,scale instead of pencil,eraser. Please help me to find out this solution. Thanks. This is a part of the code what i have done so far :

```
    LinkedHashSet<String> freq = new LinkedHashSet<String>();  
    /* Linked hashset has these items :  
    [pen,pencil,eraser,scale] */  
    String item;  
    String item2;  
    Iterator<String> itr = freq.iterator();  
    while (itr.hasNext()) {  
        item = itr.next();  
        System.out.println(item);  
        item2=itr.next();  
        System.out.println(item2);
        // perform some task  
    }
```

Comment: Comparing each pair of elements is probably best done by copying to a list and iterating the indices, otherwise it's going to be a big pain.

Comment: please share your code here which helps us to find the problem better and sooner.

Comment: Can you add the code of what you have done so far, so we can help you continue..

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand what you want well, But the looping you want must be done using nested loop, consider this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedHashSet<String> freq = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    freq.add("pen");
    freq.add("pencil");
    freq.add("eraser");
    freq.add("scale");

    for (String item : freq) {
        performeOperation(item, freq);
    }
}

private static void performeOperation(String primeItem, LinkedHashSet<String> freq) {
    for (String secondItem : freq) {
        if (primeItem != secondItem) {
            System.out.println(primeItem + ", " + secondItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Output sample:

```
pen, pencil
pen, eraser
pen, scale
pencil, pen
pencil, eraser
pencil, scale
eraser, pen
eraser, pencil
eraser, scale
scale, pen
scale, pencil
scale, eraser
```

---

If you don't need duplicate pairs, use this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedHashSet<String> freq = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    LinkedHashSet<String> param = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    freq.add("pen");
    freq.add("pencil");
    freq.add("eraser");
    freq.add("scale");
    param.addAll(freq);

    for (String item : freq) {
        param.remove(item);
        performeOperation(item, param);
    }
}

private static void performeOperation(String primeItem, LinkedHashSet<String> param) {
    for (String secondItem : param) {
        System.out.println(primeItem + ", " + secondItem);
    }
}
```

Output sample:

```
pen, pencil
pen, eraser
pen, scale
pencil, eraser
pencil, scale
eraser, scale
```

---

Yes, it can be done using one `LinkedHashSet`, but you have to use the `LinkedHashSet` to maintains the insertion order of elements, so that this solution can work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedHashSet<String> freq = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    freq.add("pen");
    freq.add("pencil");
    freq.add("eraser");
    freq.add("scale");

    for (String item : freq) {
        performeOperation(item, freq);
    }
}

private static void performeOperation(String primeItem, LinkedHashSet<String> param) {
    boolean flag = false;
    for (String secondItem : param) {
        if (flag) {
            System.out.println(primeItem + ", " + secondItem);
        } else if (primeItem.equals(secondItem)) {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this you have done using 2 linkedhash set where both contains the same elements. But i want to do that using only one linkedhashset (print without duplicate pairs) how do i do that?

Comment: Alrabee, Thanks. the updated answer worked fine and that's what i wanted. Thank you so much. :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
    Iterator<String> iterator = set.iterator();
    String pencil = iterator.next();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(pencil);
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
```

**Output:**

```
pencil
pen
pencil
eraser
pencil
scale
```

Comment: I am assuming the full list that is required is {pencil, pen}, {pencil, eraser}, {pencil, scale}, {pen,eraser}, {pen,scale}, {eraser,scale}. It needs a nested iteration

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it with ArrayLists in java, but you could convert it to an from an arraylist to a hashmap since you can count occurences using that method. here is what I would do.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.HashMap; 
    import java.util.Map; 
    import java.util.Map.Entry; 
    import java.util.*; 

    public class Sample
    {

         public static void main(String []args){
            ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            arrayList.add("Pencil");
            arrayList.add("Pencil");
            arrayList.add("Bulb");
            arrayList.add("Scale");
            arrayList.add("Pencil");
            arrayList.add("Pencil");
            arrayList.add("Scale");
            arrayList.add("Eraser");

            countListItems(arrayList);

         }

        public static void countListItems(ArrayList<String> list) 
        { 
            Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 

            for (String x : list) 
            { 
                Integer y = map.get(x); 
                map.put(x, (y == null) ? 1 : y + 1); 
            } 

            for (Entry<String, Integer> item : map.entrySet()) { 
                System.out.println(item.getKey()+" -> count="+ item.getValue()); 
            }
        } 
    }
```